# Windows CMD sort retaining header?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, csv, sorting

Need to sort in Windows a large CSV-like file with a header row (~7 million rows). Can successfully do this with a CMD command sort, but it includes the header row in the sort. I would like to keep it at the top.

I also have Notepad++ which has a sorting feature, but it fails for my two largest files (bug reported).

I am open to both suggestions involving CMD sort command and other solutions, preferably ones that can be scripted in CMD or PowerShell (which I'm not so good at yet).

Answer (score 1):

That is very easy to do in Powershell as Powershell handles the header correctly by default.

```
Import-Csv -Delimeter  ',' FILENAME | Sort -Property "Column name" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimeter ',' -Path NEW_FILENAME
```

The Delimiter parameter (on import and export) specifies the column-delimiter character. I used a comma, but some CSV's use semi-columns.
The -NoTypeInformation prevents the export to include data-type information, which is normally what you want.
Replace FILENAME with the original filename, NEWFILENAME with the desired output name.
Replace "Column name" with the name of the column (same spelling as in the header) that you want as sorting key. Use multiple -Property parameters to sort on multiple columns.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Will try and mark as answer if it works out. Might take a few days though.